# How do I calculate a column based on relative row references in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to R. I'm trying to do something that would take two seconds in Excel, so I can only assume I'm missing something!

- I have a dataframe which contains quarterly GDP data.
- I would like to add a column to this dataframe, which shows the annual growth in GDP
- I would calculate the values of this column as the current level of GDP, divided by the level of GDP four quarters ago
- I assume this would mean calculating that column as the current value of the GDP column, divided by the value of the GDP column four rows further up the data frame

So far, I have the following code:

```
gdp_url <- "https://api.ons.gov.uk/dataset/PN2/timeseries/YBEZ/data"

gdp_data <- fromJSON(txt=gdp_url)
gdp_df <- as.data.frame(gdp_data["quarters"])

gdp_df$quarters.value <- as.numeric(gdp_df$quarters.value)

gdp_df$AnnualGrowth = 0

gdp_df$AnnualGrowth = (gdp_df$quarters.value/gdp_df$quarters.value[-4]) - 1
```

However, the resulting values of the AnnualGrowth column are just plain incorrect. More to the point, `gdp_df$quarters.value[-4]` just seems to return exactly the same vector as `gdp_df$quarters.value[]`.

How do I make a relative row reference in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a lagged ratio, the following will do it.

```
AnnualGrowth <- gdp_df$quarters.value/dplyr::lag(gdp_df$quarters.value, 4) - 1
head(AnnualGrowth, 10)
#[1]          NA          NA          NA          NA 0.025751073 0.025751073
#[7] 0.000000000 0.008438819 0.020920502 0.020920502
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for what you're looking for?

`gdp_df$AnnualGrowth <- (c(gdp_df$quarters.value[-c(1:4)], rep(0, 4)) / gdp_df$quarters.value ) - 1`

Your `-4` in the index just removes the fourth value and returns the vector, you'd want to remove the first four, which is why i used `-c(1:4)` above.

`dplyr` is also a viable solution:

```
library(dplyr)
gdp_df <- gdp_df %>% mutate(AnnualGrowth = (quarters.value / lag(quarters.value, 4)) - 1)
```